# Why I can't load CSS file or images

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm learning how to make websites, and I'm stuck on a problem that I can't find a solution to, I hope you can help me.
I can't connect either a CSS file or an image for the site icon, but if I use  it works.
I'm using Node.Js for backend with EJS for frontend.

That's how I connect image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href='src/images/favicon-32x32.png'>

    <title>Title</title>
```

And that's for CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1 class="ws_title">Title</h1>
```

My css file and html template are in the same directory: src/views/project
And all the images are in the src/images

I've tried using different browsers but it's not working

Do you know what's the problem might be?

Updated: I’ve just found that with EJS I must use express.static, but I don’t understand what should I do with it, can you explain?

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned Your project and made some adjustments.

1. **Rename** `images` directory to `public` directory.
2. **Move** `style.css` file from `/views/pocketsage/` to `public` directory.
3. Add in `server.js` file [Serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), this line of code `app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`
4. `server.js`  **add** `path`,  `const path = require("path");`
5. `main.ejs` **change** `href` to `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png" />`
6. `main.ejs` **change** `src` `<img src="avatar.png" alt="" class="info-card__photo" />`
7. **Restart** the `Server` and **browser** `ctrl+f5` and Voila.

---

**Folder&file** `server.js` and `main.ejs` code snippets and output in `terminal` of **VScode**:

[image]

---

**Output** in **browser**

> http://127.0.0.1:3002/pocketsages

and `console` with `AVATAR` and `FAVICON`:
[image]

Comment: You saved me! It's working now. I thought that I'll never fix that. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I can't vote for your answer because my reputation is too low

Comment: @VuimovNikita You’re welcome ! I am happy for that ;-)